# How to convert a base64 String to a ZPL label for print on a Zebra ZQ630 printer

Tags: android, base64, printers, zpl

For context, our application is an *Android WebView* that loads a url (web app written in *React*) with a print feature. The flow of the app is that once the print button is clicked, it triggers a print method on the Android side through an @Javascript Interface bringing with it a payload - **A base 64 String**, that we convert in the Android side of code to print. Note -- ( The printer is connected to the android device )

Issue is that the conversion is coming out like [image: this] instead of like [image: this].

To further complicate the issue, on base64decode.net using google chrome, the conversion presents no issues, but if you try the same payload on the same site using Safari, it ends up scrambled as in our app as also shown above.

I have tried using Zebra SDK Base64 API and none seems to help thus far.

I've tried to convert the Base64 String on the React side of my app using atob but even when it successfully converts and displays this code. On Labelary.com it wouldn't generate any image and throws error.

I guess my question would be if anyone has experienced this before and does anyone know a way around it. --A good say to generate a ZPL string that would work on Labelary.com either on Java or Javascript

// This code is the result of atob conversion that wouldn't generate a ZPL on labelary.com

```
^XA
^PW812
^CI13
^FT0,510^GB809,0,2^FS
^FT0,423^GB809,0,20^FS
^FT244,402^GB0,215,2^FS
^FT0,187^GB809,0,2^FS
^FT20,20^A0N,18,22^FDJCPENNEY.COM^FS
^FT20,43^A0N,18,22^FD5555 SCARBOROUGH BLVD^FS
^FT20,65^A0N,18,22^FDCOLUMBUS OH 43232^FS
^FT447,30^A0N,23,29^FD1 LBS^FS
^FT630,30^A0N,23,29^FD1 OF 1^FS
^FT20,122^A0N,28,35^FDSHIP^FS
^FT20,150^A0N,28,35^FD TO:^FS
^FT122,118^A0N,23,29^FDUSPS 48182^FS
^FT122,144^A0N,23,29^FD8149 LEWIS AVE^FS
^FT122,177^A0N,28,35^FH^FDTEMPERANCE MI 48182_F09998^FS
^FT20,396^BD2^FH^FD988840481829998[)>_1E01_1D961Z00316075_1DUPSN_1DW2A813_1E07L$4Y29L'_1D+_1DH:ZGX/,ZX2&O#( *XZ6F+XD1A/*_0D:+GDI_0D_1E_04^FS
^FT284,252^A0N,65,81^FH^FD MI 482 0_F001 X^FS
^BY4,,102^FT330,382^BCN,,N^FD>;420481829998^FS
^FT20,467^A0N,42,52^FDUPS SUREPOST^FS
^FT20,500^A0N,23,29^FDTRACKING #: 1Z W2A 813 YW 0031 6075^FS
^FT687,508^GB122,0,85^FS
^BY3,,142^FT106,664^BCN,,N^FD>:1ZW2A813YW>500316075^FS
^FT0,695^GB809,0,14^FS
^FT20,721^A0N,28,35^FDUSPS DELIVER TO:^FS
^FT20,743^A0N,18,22^FDMARCIA SMOTHERMAN^FS
^FT20,765^A0N,18,22^FD268 HIGHLANDS^FS
^FT20,787^A0N,18,22^FH^FDTEMPERANCE MI 48182_F01189^FS
^FT356,721^A0N,18,22^FH^FDCarrier_F0Leave^FS
^FT356,746^A0N,18,22^FDIf No Response^FS
^FT569,813^GB213,112,2^FS
^FT603,723^A0N,18,22^FH^FDPARCEL SELECT^FS
^FT586,747^A0N,18,22^FH^FDU.S. POSTAGE PAID^FS
^FT658,771^A0N,18,22^FH^FDUPS^FS
^FT659,795^A0N,18,22^FH^FDeVS^FS
^FT0,839^GB809,0,14^FS
^FT221,883^A0N,32,40^FDUSPS TRACKING # eVS^FS
^BY3,,156^FT40,1079^BCN,,N^FD>;>842048182>892612909859896551001000113^FS
^FT156,1135^A0N,28,35^FD9261 2909 8598 9655 1001 0001 13^FS
^FT0,1148^GB809,0,8^FS
^FT508,1193^A0N,23,29^FDREF1: 2020066410165651^FS
^FT508,1215^A0N,23,29^FDContainer ID: 307497242^FS
^BY2,,30^FT20,1189^BCN,,N^FD>;257977480900^FS
^FT20,1215^A0N,23,29^FD257977480900^FS
^XZ
```

Note: I've had some other base64 String conversion that worked well but not all of them. Below is the same code - converted on Base64decode.net on Chrome but it works well on Labelary.com

```
 ^XA
^PW812
^CI13
^FT0,510^GB809,0,2^FS
^FT0,423^GB809,0,20^FS
^FT244,402^GB0,215,2^FS
^FT0,187^GB809,0,2^FS
^FT20,20^A0N,18,22^FDJCPENNEY.COM^FS
^FT20,43^A0N,18,22^FD5555 SCARBOROUGH BLVD^FS
^FT20,65^A0N,18,22^FDCOLUMBUS OH 43232^FS
^FT447,30^A0N,23,29^FD1 LBS^FS
^FT630,30^A0N,23,29^FD1 OF 1^FS
^FT20,122^A0N,28,35^FDSHIP^FS
^FT20,150^A0N,28,35^FD TO:^FS
^FT122,118^A0N,23,29^FDUSPS 48182^FS
^FT122,144^A0N,23,29^FD8149 LEWIS AVE^FS
^FT122,177^A0N,28,35^FH^FDTEMPERANCE MI 48182_F09998^FS
^FT20,396^BD2^FH^FD988840481829998[)>_1E01_1D961Z00316075_1DUPSN_1DW2A813_1E07L$4Y29L'_1D+_1DH:ZGX/,ZX2&O#( *XZ6F+XD1A/*_0D:+GDI_0D_1E_04^FS
^FT284,252^A0N,65,81^FH^FD MI 482 0_F001 X^FS
^BY4,,102^FT330,382^BCN,,N^FD>;420481829998^FS
^FT20,467^A0N,42,52^FDUPS SUREPOST^FS
^FT20,500^A0N,23,29^FDTRACKING #: 1Z W2A 813 YW 0031 6075^FS
^FT687,508^GB122,0,85^FS
^BY3,,142^FT106,664^BCN,,N^FD>:1ZW2A813YW>500316075^FS
^FT0,695^GB809,0,14^FS
^FT20,721^A0N,28,35^FDUSPS DELIVER TO:^FS
^FT20,743^A0N,18,22^FDMARCIA SMOTHERMAN^FS
^FT20,765^A0N,18,22^FD268 HIGHLANDS^FS
^FT20,787^A0N,18,22^FH^FDTEMPERANCE MI 48182_F01189^FS
^FT356,721^A0N,18,22^FH^FDCarrier_F0Leave^FS
^FT356,746^A0N,18,22^FDIf No Response^FS
^FT569,813^GB213,112,2^FS
^FT603,723^A0N,18,22^FH^FDPARCEL SELECT^FS
^FT586,747^A0N,18,22^FH^FDU.S. POSTAGE PAID^FS
^FT658,771^A0N,18,22^FH^FDUPS^FS
^FT659,795^A0N,18,22^FH^FDeVS^FS
^FT0,839^GB809,0,14^FS
^FT221,883^A0N,32,40^FDUSPS TRACKING # eVS^FS
^BY3,,156^FT40,1079^BCN,,N^FD>;>842048182>892612909859896551001000113^FS
^FT156,1135^A0N,28,35^FD9261 2909 8598 9655 1001 0001 13^FS
^FT0,1148^GB809,0,8^FS
^FT508,1193^A0N,23,29^FDREF1: 2020066410165651^FS
^FT508,1215^A0N,23,29^FDContainer ID: 307497242^FS
^BY2,,30^FT20,1189^BCN,,N^FD>;257977480900^FS
^FT20,1215^A0N,23,29^FD257977480900^FS
^XZ
```

Finally, this is the base64 String in question:

> 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

Answer (score 0):

**Convert your base64 String to UTF-8 using this code:**

```
String Mybase64 = "dGVjaFBhC3M=";
//1- Convert to byte
byte[] X = Base64.decode(Mybase64); 
//2- Convert to UTF-8
String ZPL_Result = new String(X, "UTF-8");
```

**Update***

```
string b64 = "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";
byte[] data = Base64.decode(b64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String ZPL_Result = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I tried that and on that particular ZPL label, the decoded string comes out scrambled as in the picture above.

Comment: I'm really sorry :| ,I just notice that you are using java and my code is C#

Answer (score 0):

Figured I leave an answer here on the approach I employed. I resorted to creating a regex expression to filter out the unicode characters that was appearing in the conversion. That way I had a clean String to print.

The precise unicode character is "u + FFFD"